# Virtual Key combination

Tags: c++, virtual, virtual-keyboard

I'm looking for C++ help with virtual key combination, I'm looking for a simple key combination to do a action. I'm trying to get Shift+G to work. I've tried what I know and it's given me different results but nothing what I'm trying to do.

```
if (VK_SHIFT & 0x47) // Shift+G test
{
    if(::GetKeyState(0x47)<0);      
    {
        CBaseItem* pItemInfo = g_pItemTableHash->GetData(
            g_pMainPlayer->m_pInv_Guardian[0].GetID());

        if (GUARDIAN_ITEM_TYPE_ADULT == pItemInfo->BaseItem_Guardian.bType)
        {
            if(CUserInterface::GetInstance()->m_bGuardian==FALSE)
            {               
                // ON //
                CTDS_DUNGEON_CALLGARDIAN CallGuardinan;
                CallGuardinan.bZipCode = 0;
                g_pNet->SendMsg( (char*)&CallGuardinan, CallGuardinan.GetPacketSize(),
                    SERVER_INDEX_ZONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all that really matters is the first line, any one know how I can fix this so key combination SHIFT+G works?

Comment: Why is c# a tag on here?

Comment: shouldn't you be comparing `VK_SHIFT & 0x47` to something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `GetKeyState(0x47)!=0` ? or rather  `GetKeyState(0x47)&0x8000` to keep the high order byte only ?

Comment: if `(VK_SHIFT & 0x47)`

Is the part I'm searching help for. It doesn't input the correct key combination, when tested.

Comment: @FredSantiago this if gets never executed. I completed my answer to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem in your code is the `;`  at the end of

```
 if(::GetKeyState(0x47)<0);      // !!!!!
```

The `;` causes the following indented inner if-block to be executed in any case !

Here a similar simplified code that works very well:

```
    while(true) {
        if(::GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)  // is shift pressed ?  
        {
            if(::GetKeyState(0x47) & 0x8000)  // if G also pressed ?  
            {
                std::cout << "Shift G pressed" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else std::cout << "Shift..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

***Additional infos:***

The expression `(VK_SHIFT & 0x47)` is a constant which is completely independent of the input. [`VK_SHIFT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is `0x10` and `0x10 & 0x47` yields 0. So your outer if-block gets never executed.